# Exporting two vectors layer as one image

Tags: pyqgis, image, vector-layer

I am writing Python code to take two vector layers as input add different symbology to it and then export that as a image. The vectors layers have been added to the map canvas but while exporting only the second vector file in the image not both vector file.

```
  import os

  w_layer = r"path to first vector layer"

  o_layer = r"path to second vector layer"

  image_location = r"export image path"

  wlayer = QgsVectorLayer(w_layer, "W layer", "ogr")

  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(wlayer)

  wlayer.loadNamedStyle(r"path for qml file to display a particular symbology")



  olayer = QgsVectorLayer(o_layer, "o layer", "ogr")

  QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(olayer)

  olayer.loadNamedStyle(r"path to qml file to display a particular symbology")




   vlayer = iface.addMapLayers(wlayer , olayer)

   settings = QgsMapSettings()

   settings.setLayers([vlayer])

   settings.setBackgroundColor(QColor(255, 255, 255))

   settings.setOutputSize(QSize(800, 600))

   settings.setExtent(vlayer.extent())



   render = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(settings)


   def finished():

      img = render.renderedImage()


      img.save(image_location, "png")

   render.finished.connect(finished)


   render.start() `
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Buggy sample `iface.addMapLayers` does not exist (remove it) So `settings.setLayers([vlayer])` can't work. Use `settings.setLayers([wlayer, olayer])`

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG77 , it worked

Comment: Made an answer with same content so the question can be set to answered

Answer (score 1):

In the original code, `iface.addMapLayers` does not exist not anywhere in the doc e.g https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html. So, simply remove it.

Because of the previous remark, `settings.setLayers([vlayer])` can't work as `vlayer` content is `None`.

Use `settings.setLayers([wlayer, olayer])` instead to solve your issue.